# Combining date and UTC time fields in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 separate fields for date and time. The time field is stored in UTC time. How can I combine the 2 into a datetime field into local time

Example:

```
date: 2021-03-08
time in UTC: 23:00
time zone: GMT+8
```

I would like to get `2021-03-08 07:00 in local time`

or even `2021-03-07 23:00` in UTC

Note: Combining the fields is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: `select '2021-03-08'::date + '23:00'::time; 2021-03-08 23:00:00`

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver but the time is stored in UTC. In this instance the datetime should either be `2021-03-07 23:00` or `2021-03-08 07:00`

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Making `2021-03-08 23:00` = `2021-03-07 23:00` seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the local timezone is GMT+08

Comment: I got that, but what you asking for is that `2021-03-08 23:00 = 2021-03-07 23:00` and that is not the case.

Comment: What's your time zone?

Comment: @Abelisto, that yields(given TimeZone='+8') `2021-03-08 23:00:00`, which is not @HalahAb wants and that is `2021-03-07 23:00` or `2021-03-08 07:00` and are not possible unless you use some arbitrary criteria and dubious math.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, you are right, should be `select ('2021-03-08'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC')::date + '23:00'::time;` to get the value at UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Need to know your time zone to convert. To convert utc to america/los_angeles time zone:

```
select '2021-03-08 23:00'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'america/los_angeles'
```

you can check out below codes:

If you have a timestamp without time zone column and you're storing timestamps as UTC, you need to tell PostgreSQL that, and then tell it to convert it to your local time zone.

```
select created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/los_angeles'
from users;
```

To be more concise, you can also use the abbreviation for the time zone:

```
select created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'pst'
from users;
```

To see the list of time zones PostgreSQL supports:

select * from pg_timezone_names;

Answer (score 1):

SInce the time difference is 8 hours, try

```
SELECT '2021-03-08'::date + ('23:00'::time + '8 hours'::interval);
```

If you want this to work with arbitrary time zones, the query becomes more complicated:

```
SELECT '2021-03-08'::date
     + ((current_date + '23:00'::time)
        AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
        AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Ulaanbaatar'
       )::time;
```

Comment: Thanks this does solve it, but it will get complicated when other timezones are used.